# Class for Managing Office Details

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public class Office
{
    private Int32 _SyncID;
    private string _OfficeName;

    #region Properties
    public Int32 SyncID
    {
        get { return _SyncID; }
        set { _SyncID = value; }
    }
    public string OfficeName
    {
        get { return _OfficeName; }
        set { _OfficeName = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    public void GetOffice(int syncID)
    {
        List<Office> results = new List<Office>();

        var sql = @"
Select so.SyncID, 
   so.title
From Offices o
Left Outer Join SyncOffices so On so.id = o.SyncID
Where o.SyncID = @syncID
"; 

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Settings.ConnectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@syncID", syncID);
            connection.Open();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var office = new Office();
                    office.SyncID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    office.OfficeName = reader.GetString(1);
                    results.Add(office);
                }
            }
        }

        this.SyncID = results.FirstOrDefault().SyncID;
        this.OfficeName = results.FirstOrDefault().OfficeName;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current code will ensure that the list has only one entry (i.e. the last one) ...

```
results = new List<Office>();
results.Add(office);
```

... because invoking `results = new List<Office>()` will discard any previous list elements.

If you expect your SQL `join where` to produce exactly one (or, zero or one but not more than one) element then you can assert that; perhaps something like ...

```
if (reader.Read())
    ... get the data ...
if (reader.Read())
    throw new Exception("Too many rows");
```

... or ...

```
string rc = null;
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (rc != null)
        throw new Exception("Too many rows");
    rc = reader.GetString(1);
}
```

Perhaps your `GetOffice` method could be the `Office` constructor; or be a static factory method of Office.